# Adding Tags in DynamoDB GlobalTable CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I need to add some tags for DynamoDB Global table CFT ,trying to write one sample cft below .

Here I have creating resource for dynamoDB Global Table with KMS key and adding tags inside SSESpecification:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS CloudFormation Template to create global tables
Resources:
  globalTableExample:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable'
    Properties:
      TableName: sample1
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: PK
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: PK
          KeyType: HASH
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
        SSEType: "KMS"
      Replicas:
        - Region: us-east-1
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: mytable
      - Key: Region
        Value: east

 
         

getting error **Properties validation failed for resource globalTableExample with message: #: extraneous key [Tags] is not permitted**
```

Could someone please suggest me how to use tag ?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Properties validation failed for resource globalTableExample with message: #: extraneous key [Tags] is not permitted

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the tags under the Replica resource, as the tags belong to the replica and not the global table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-globaltable-replicaspecification.html